# Gradient of $X \mapsto a^T X b$ when $X$ is symmetric

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, scalar-fields

For matrix $X \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, $a \in \Bbb R^n$, and $b \in \Bbb R^n$, I know the following holds

$$\nabla_X \left( a^T X b \right) = a{b^T}$$

However, it seems that if $X$ is a symmetric matrix ($X \in \Bbb S^n$), then

$$ \nabla_X \left( {a^T} X b \right) = \frac{1}{2}(a{b^T} + {b}a^T) $$

How to understand it? If $X \in \Bbb S^n$, then the dimension of $X$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Why should we get $n^2$ elements after differentiation?

Answer (score 7):

Define a non-standard symmetrizing operation for a square matrix ($A$) as 
$$
  {\rm nsym}(A) = A + A^T - I\circ A
$$
Now suppose that you have determined the differential of some scalar-valued function $f(X)$ to be
$$
  df = A:dX
$$
Later you are told that $X$ is constrained to be symmetric. How does such a constraint modify the unconstrained result?  The answer is to use nsym() 
$$
  df = {\rm nsym}(A):dX
$$
Applying this to the current problem yields
$$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = ab^T + ba^T - {\rm diag}(a\circ b)
$$
A lot of people mistakenly apply the standard symmetrizing operator, i.e.
$$
  {\rm sym}(A) = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)
$$
in this situation.

BTW, if the constraint is to be diagonal, then the symmetrizing operation to apply is
$$
  {\rm dsym}(A) = I\circ A
$$

Comment: This is a great answer. Could you please provide a reference or an explanation? The only other place where I have seen this is in [these notes by Thomas Minka](https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf) but even there it's just a one line explanation. Also, if the goal is to solve for $X$ after setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}=0$, then using $\mathrm{sym}$ or $\mathrm{nsym}$ should make no difference since both would translate into $\alpha\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{i,j}}=0$ and $\beta\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{i,i}}=0$, isn't it?

Comment: @LucaCiti I hope this is still useful.. check out eq. 138 -- or more generally, section 2.8, of [the matrix cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf)

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06491.pdf) suggests that one is not mistaken to use the standard `sym()` operator in this case. Rather it is the application of `csym()` which produces a subtle error.

Answer (score 6):

### It is the notation what causes confusion!

If we define
\begin{align*}
    \phi\,\colon\, &\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}\\
              &Y\mapsto a^TYb
\end{align*}
it is certainly true that
$$
    \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_{ij}}(Y) = a_ib_j=(ab^T)_{ij}
$$

irrespectively of whether $Y$ is symmetric or not. This fact is easily verified by observing that $\phi$ is linear and therefore equal to its differential, i.e.,
$$
    D\phi(Y) = \phi\qquad\text{or}\qquad
          D\phi(Y)(M) = a^TMb\quad (M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})
$$
This allows us to write
$$
    \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_{ij}}(Y) = D\phi(Y)(E_{ij}) = a^TE_{ij}b = a_ib_j,
$$
which corresponds to your partial derivative w.r.t. $X$. Equivalently
$$
    \nabla\phi(Y) = ab^T.
$$
However, there is another interpretation for the same notation, which becomes clear if we name the functions we use. Consider the following diagrams

[image]
[image]

where $\iota$ is the natural embedding, $\pi$ the projection $\pi(Y)=(1/2)(Y+Y^T)$, $\phi$ is as above, $\bar{\phi}$ is just the restriction of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is given by
$$
    \psi(Y) = a^T(Y+Y^T)b/2.
$$
These diagrams aren't equivalent. In fact, the one on the left does not commute with regards to $\pi$, while the one on the right fully commutes.

Now, if we reason as we did above for $\phi$, this time for $\psi$, we get
$$
      \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x_{ij}}(Y) = D\psi(Y)(E_{ij})
         = \psi(E_{ij}) = a^T(E_{ij}+E_{ji})b/2 = (a_ib_j+a_jb_i)/2,
$$
and therefore
$$
    \nabla\psi(Y) = (ab^T + ba^T)/2.
$$
This explains why there appears to be two different partial derivatives, it is just that we are taking derivatives of two different functions and the (simplified) notation (which disregards function names) cannot distinguish between them.

Comment: This is a great answer that I'm trying to digest. Correct me if I am wrong, but does the commutitivity of the diagrams come down to the fact that for the right diagram we have $\pi \bar\phi = \psi$ for any arbitrary (possibly non-symmetric) matrix, but in the left diagram we have $\pi \bar\phi \neq \phi$? Does this then imply that the symmetric derivative is superfluous in situations where you know your matrix is symmetric to start with?

Comment: We have two derivatives that depend only on parameters $a$ and $b$, regardless of the independent variable $Y$, ignoring the symmetry of $Y$ which plays no role in the final results. The issue is due to a poor notation (or abuse of notation, if you want to be polite), as it fails to differentiate between two extensions of the same function, $\bar\phi$, resulting in two different outcomes: extensions $\psi$ and $\phi$. Extension $\psi$ is more *predictable* as it can be derived from $\bar\phi$ by composition with $\pi$, unlike $\phi$. This might make $\psi$ a better choice in some situations.