# Quadratic form matrix derivative confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $R$ is square-symmetrix matrix. Then we have that
$$ x^T R y = y^T R x$$
Now if I take matrix derivative of these two wrt. $R$, then this would seem to imply

$$ xy^T = yx^T$$ Yet this is not true, rather they are transposes of each other.

a.) Is this because taking transpose of scalar matters when I am taking derivative wrt. a matrix

b.) If I have to take this derivative as part of larger expression, how to best decide which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R$ is symmetric, $R_{ij}$ appears twice in $x\cdot Ry$ if $i\ne j$, so the correct differentiation is $x^Ty+y^Tx=y^Tx+x^Ty$, which is trivial.

Comment: Now, that makes sense -- thanks

Comment: Didn't find these before, but for anyone interested -- more detail also in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150197/matrix-derivatives-for-symmetric-matrices) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613704/what-is-the-matrix-derivative-of-a-symmetric-bilinear-form-mathbfat-x-math?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131708/understanding-notation-of-derivatives-of-a-matrix)